# Location of pgadmin4 config_local.py on Windows

Tags: pgadmin

What directory should the pgadmin4 `config_local.py` be put into on Windows?
Have tried `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\` without luck. Using PgAdmin v5.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `config_local.py` file should be created in the same directory as `config.py` which for pgAdmin 5.3 on Windows is `C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\web`.

If you want to make system-wide customizations you can also use `C:\Program Files\Common Files\pgAdmin\config_system.py` which doesn't require adding files into the install directory.

For more details see the documentation at https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/config_py.html.

Answer (score 4):

The documented location `%CommonProgramFiles%\pgadmin` doesn't exist on my computer, but I found `config.py` in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v6\web`.

I'm using version 6.10.

Answer (score 1):

If you install pgAdmin with PostgreSQL from executable file, `config.py` location is under PostgreSQL and for version 14 of PostgreSQL, full path is like this: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web`.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin 6.10: `%ProgramFiles%\pgAdmin 4\v6\web`

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin since v8.0 : `%ProgramFiles%\pgAdmin 4\web`
So if upgrading from an earlier version you will lose these settings (unless you copy config_local.py of course), but they will be preserved when upgrading to later versions.